# SQL: Efficient way to get group by results including all table columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's consider a simple table below.

| id | code | marks | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 100 | A |
| 2 | Y | 120 | B |
| 3 | Z | 130 | A |
| 4 | X | 120 | C |
| 5 | Y | 100 | A |
| 6 | Z | 110 | B |
| 7 | X | 150 | A |
| 8 | X | 140 | C |

**Goal:** Get maximum marks for each grade, return all the columns.

| id | code | marks | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | X | 150 | A |
| 2 | Y | 120 | B |
| 8 | X | 140 | C |

This is very simple if I don't want `id` and `code` column

```
select grade, max(marks)
from table
group by grade;
```

What could be the most efficient query to get `id` and `code` column in the above query?

I tried something like this which didn't work

```
select * from table t
inner join
(select grade, max(marks)
from table
group by grade) a
on a.grade=t.grade;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres the most efficient way for this kind of query is to use (the proprietary) `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (grade) *
from the_table t
order by grade, marks desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a correlated subquery?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.marks = (select max(t2.marks) from t t2 where t2.grade = t.grade);
```